# Prevent infinite loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

Should be quite a simple one. I want this jQuery animation to stop running after 1 loop, rather than an infinite loop.

It's most definitely something simple, but this is code I had help with a while back and I can't for the life of me figure out why it is looping.

Thanks.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SFejj/ and the code:

```
function move(jElem, bUp, iSpeed) {
    jElem.animate(
        {
         opacity: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '0.1',
         width: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200',
         height: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200'},
        iSpeed,
        function() {
            move(jElem, !bUp, iSpeed);
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navImage').each(function(iIndex, jElem) {
        // get random delay
        var iTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        // get random speed
        var iSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1500;
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                move($(jElem), true, iSpeed);
            }, 
            iTime
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the move function calling the move function recursively.  Good way to cause a stack overflow!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the callback on the animate which was calling move again.

```
function move(jElem, bUp, iSpeed) {
    jElem.animate(
        {
           opacity: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '0.1',
           width: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200',
           height: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200'
        },iSpeed
    );
}
```

You were doing this before

```
function move(jElem, bUp, iSpeed) {
    jElem.animate(
      {
         opacity: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '0.1',
         width: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200',
         height: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200'},
         iSpeed,
         function() {                      
            move(jElem, !bUp, iSpeed);   // move will be called at the end of animate recursively
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Won't this only run the function once? I thought the OP wanted to loop the function once (meaning a total of two times) and then stop, although I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it loop 1 time, just add a variable that increments by 1. You can change the line `loopTimes < 1` to make the function stop looping after any number of loops you desire.

```
function move(jElem, bUp, iSpeed, loopTimes) {
    jElem.animate(
        {
         opacity: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '0.1',
         width: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200',
         height: (bUp ? '+' : '-') + '=200'},
        iSpeed,
                    if(loopTimes < 1)
                    {
                       loopTimes++;
                       function() {
                           move(jElem, !bUp, iSpeed, loopTimes);
                       }
                    }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navImage').each(function(iIndex, jElem) {
        // get random delay
        var iTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        // get random speed
        var iSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1500;
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                move($(jElem), true, iSpeed, 0);
            }, 
            iTime
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually now that I look at it I think the syntax is wrong for doing that inside of an animate call like that, but passing a variable like that is the general concept.